# SQL query to fetch rows where a value is present in a comma separated field

Tags: mysql

what is the Query For -> How To Get The table content whose column consists of data comma sepreted value how to check is that value is present in that coloumn if present then select that ID of product

```
id   productname  poduct_cat_id
1    abc          2,3,4
2    def          3,4
3    efg          1,2,5
```

How to check 3 in product_cat_id and get the product name and id

output: result[id]=1
        result[productname]=abc

Comment: What is the structure of your table?  Can you also provide sample data and desired output please?

Comment: Implement a real *many-to-many* relationship and you won't run into these ridiculous problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Phil's comment above.

For you table you can use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3, product_cat_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a leading and trailing comma to the field, then you can use a straightforward like expression to select the rows of interest.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(',', product_cat_id, ',') LIKE '%,3,%'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) will be your friend here I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, productname
from table
where product_cat_id like '%,3,%'
or product_cat_id like '3,%'
or product_cat_id like '%,3'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't consider changing the structure of the table... sight:

This is a lame query:

```
SELECT `id`,`productname` 
FROM `place_table_name_here` 
WHERE `poduct_cat_id` LIKE '%3%';
```

but it will give you the answer.

Comment: that won't work.. assume product_cat_id = '12,13,14', your query will return this row, even though it doesn't contain the id 3