# sql matching users that have activities in common

Tags: mysql, sql, matching

so, i have a table with users and activities

```
users
id | activities
1 | "-2-3-4-"
2 | "-3-4-"
3 | "-1-2-3-4-"

activities
id | title
1 | running
2 | walking 
3 | climbing
4 | singing
```

and I am trying for a user with id 3 to find users that have at least two same activities
what I tried to do is this

```
SELECT u.id FROM users u 
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM activities a 
        WHERE a.id IN(TRIM( ',' FROM REPLACE( u.activities, '-', ',' ) )) 
AND a.id IN(1,2,3) ) >= 2
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is table activities and table users have any relation in between them

Comment: Oh!When inserting new activity are you updating your table with concat command

Comment: @AnkitGautam no, I update that row manualy,

Comment: I dont do concat I just rewrite it with new values, but that doesnt matter ;)

Comment: Change your user table syntax and create different rows for different activity for each user

Comment: Hopefully this will work

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980815/sql-query-to-fetch-rows-where-a-value-is-present-in-a-comma-separated-field

cheers!

Comment: [This post](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx) comes to mind...

Answer (score 1):

For the love of god, make a 3rd table that contains user_id and activity_id.

This isn't a suitable solution in any way.

You should have a table which makes the connection between users and activities, not store all activities in a row in your users table.

Comment: I know that :) but since this is allready made like this I dont want to rewrite it ;)

Comment: You should, it will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

Comment: in future it wont be any other manipulations with this, otherwise I would do it

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a function that takes the user.activities string and splits the string in activities int ids like this:

```
create FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringToIds (@acts nvarchar(MAX))
RETURNS @acivityids TABLE (Id int)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @stringToInsert nvarchar (max) 
set @stringToInsert=''
DECLARE @intToInsert int 
set @intToInsert=0
DECLARE @stidx int 
set @stidx=0
DECLARE @endidx int 
set @endidx=0

WHILE LEN(@acts) > 3
BEGIN
    set @stidx=CHARINDEX('-', @acts, 1)
    set @acts=substring(@acts,@stidx+1,len(@acts))
    set @endidx=CHARINDEX('-', @acts, 1)-1

    set @stringToInsert=substring(@acts,1,@endidx)
    set @intToInsert=cast(@stringToInsert as int)
    INSERT INTO @acivityids
    VALUES
    (
    @intToInsert
    )

    END


-- Return the result of the function
RETURN
```

END
GO

and then you can try something like this to get the users that have 2 and more same activities with user with id=3

```
select u.id,count(u.id) as ActivitiesCounter from users as u
cross apply SplitStringToIds(u.activities) as v
where v.id in (select v.id from users as u
cross apply SplitStringToIds(u.activities) as v
where u.id=3)
group by u.id having count(u.id)>=2
```

But i think that this way of storing relationships between tables is going to give you only troubles and its better to add a relationship table if you can.